# Issue with Embedding Paginated Report in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-paginated-reports

We've developed a Paginated Report with a parameter that allows the end user to specify the number of rows for download, integrated within the TOPN clauses. This parameter functions correctly in local executions.

However, after embedding the report in Power BI and executing it in Power BI Service, we encountered a memory error message, even when using a relatively small number like 6000. Monitoring the Task Manager during report execution, we observed a significant increase in CPU and memory usage

[image]
[image]

However, when we execute the paginated report directly in Power BI Service, it handles over 70,000 records (almost the entire dataset) without issues or excessive resource consumption

[image]

Our question is: why does the visual of the paginated report exhibit this problem in Power BI? Is there a specific configuration setting that might be missing in Power BI?

Comment: Can you provide more information on how the TopN parameter is being passed? Can you share the code snapshot you are using for passing the parameter for TopN filter.

Comment: Hi @Madhav I have edited the post. The TopN is working fine. This seems to be more related with the visual for paginated report in Power BI.

Comment: Refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-paginated-reports?tabs=customers#step-2---create-a-capacity) and check if you have the sufficient capacity assigned.